# Passing username (and viewing as uneditable in html) in form Django

Tags: python, django, web

I have a form where I would like to have a username and production line send along. The thing is that the username should be taken from current logged user (and viewed as uneditable field) but the production line should be selected via dorpdown.

It works by somehow since when I click on "User" dropdown it shows only the logged user.

views:

```
def order(request):
    storage = PartNumber.objects.all()
    username = request.user.username
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order_form = OrderForm(username=username, data=request.POST)
        if order_form.is_valid():
            order_form.save()
            return redirect('order')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        order_form = OrderForm(username=username)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/order.html', {"form": order_form, "username": username})
```

forms:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('end_user_id', 'production_line_id')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.pop('username', None)
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['end_user_id'].queryset = User.objects.filter(username=username)
```

models:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    end_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    production_line_id = models.OneToOneField(ProductionLine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.status)
```

html:

```
{% extends 'dashboard/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap %}
{% block content %}


<h3>Zamowienie</h3>
<br>

<!--{{ form|bootstrap }}-->
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Uzytkownik </label>
        <!--<input class="form-control" placeholder="{{user}}" readonly>-->
        {{ form.end_user_id }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Linia produkcyjna </label>
        {{ form.production_line_id }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Przeslij</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Now if you look at the html above, the commented line :

```
<!--<input class="form-control" placeholder="{{user}}" readonly>-->
```

actually gives me the look I want but doesn't send the username (doesn't work)

I was trying different solutions from different posts that I found here but nothing seems to work for me.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing username to the template using the variable `username`.
In the template you are trying to get the username by using the variable `user`.

`<input class="form-control" placeholder="{{user}}" readonly>`

Should be :

`<input class="form-control" placeholder="{{username}}" readonly>`